# Postman socket.io not working with Rust socketioxide. Gives error Unexpected server response: 404

Tags: sockets, rust, websocket, socket.io, postman

I am brand new to socket.io. I am trying to use `socketioxide` in Rust using one of the simple examples here:

https://docs.rs/socketioxide/latest/socketioxide/

Here's my `main.rs`:

```
use socketioxide::{extract::{Data, SocketRef}, SocketIo};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (layer, io) = SocketIo::new_layer();

    io.ns("/", on_connect);

    let app = axum::Router::new().layer(layer);

    axum::serve(tokio::net::TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:8080").await.unwrap(), app).await.unwrap()
}

async fn on_connect(socket: SocketRef) {
    println!("socket connected: {}", socket.id);

    socket.on(
        "join",
        |socket: SocketRef, Data::<String>(room)| async move {
            println!("Received join: {:?} from {}", room, socket.id);
        },
    );
}
```

I am unable to connect to this from Postman on the same machine. When I use the url `ws://localhost:8080/`, it gives me error:

```
Unexpected server response: 404
```

Screenshot of Postman:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like you're making a Socket.IO connection from Postman, it looks like you're making a regular websocket connection (Socket.IO is a protocol over multiple transport methods of which websockets are only one of them). Your screen doesn't look like [this](https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-socket-io/) to me. If you want this to connect from a regular websocket, you'd need to include an additional path prefix which by default is `/socket.io/` (but then, I'm not sure that's terribly useful besides debugging since Socket.IO has its own message format you'd have to follow).

Comment: @kmdreko thanks, that was it. By clicking on that tiny icon on the top left, I was able to switch from web socket to socket.io and then it worked.